# How to remove specific element from element array in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

Example:

```
<div id="Elmnt_1" class="MyElement">
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">
<div id="Elmnt_3" class="MyElement">
<div id="Elmnt_4" class="MyElement">
```

How to select all element which have class="MyElement" and omit one element from it using specific id

My guess:

```
var fltrdElmnts = $(".MyElement").filter(! $( "#Elmnt_2" ) );
fltrdElmnts.remove();
```

Expected result:

```
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">
```

Comment: How about just using `$('#Elmnt_3')` when you just want to get that element only?

Comment: @palash actually i want to hide all elements exept one specific element

Comment: Ok, I was bit confused as you had the code `fltrdElmnts.remove();` which is unnecessary, if you just want one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:not()` pseudo class inside selector.

```
$(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2)")
```

```js
$(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2)").css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Elmnt_1" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_3" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_4" class="MyElement">Div</div>
```

Or you can use `.not()` method.

```
$(".MyElement").not('#Elmnt_2')
```

```js
$(".MyElement").not('#Elmnt_2').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Elmnt_1" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_3" class="MyElement">Div</div>
<div id="Elmnt_4" class="MyElement">Div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `:not()` selector for that

```
var fltrdElmnts = $(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2");
```

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var fltrdElmnts = $(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2");
  fltrdElmnts.remove();
  /* or just:
  $(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2").remove();
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Elmnt_1" class="MyElement">Elmnt_1</div>
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">Elmnt_2</div>
<div id="Elmnt_3" class="MyElement">Elmnt_3</div>
<div id="Elmnt_4" class="MyElement">Elmnt_4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this selector `MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2)`

```js
var fltrdElmnts = $(".MyElement:not(#Elmnt_2)");
fltrdElmnts.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Elmnt_1" class="MyElement">a</div>
<div id="Elmnt_2" class="MyElement">b</div>
<div id="Elmnt_3" class="MyElement">c</div>
<div id="Elmnt_4" class="MyElement">d</div>
```

## Doc

- [`:not() Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)